# How to use RxSwift in project with Objective-C code?

Tags: swift, objective-c, rx-swift

I am working in a old project that mixes Objective-C and Swift, there is a lot of legacy code in Objective-C, so migrating everything to Swift is not realistic. New code is written in Swift but Objective-C needs to be mantained with small updates.

And I have been working with RxSwift recently and I want to start using in this old project too.

The problem is the Objective-C <-> Swift interoperability.

e.g. I can't write this:

```
@objc let int = BehaviorSubject<Int>(value: 42)
```

Because I get *Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C*

How can I deal with this situation? Is anyone using RxSwift in a mixed objc/swift project?

Comment: "I can't write this" Why do you _need_ to write that? Why does ObjC code need to see a `BehaviourSubject`?

Comment: I need to subscribe to changes to that property from both Swifth and ObjC code...

Comment: You just said "New code is written in Swift" so you seem to be breaking your own rules if you need to subscribe to changes to that _in ObjC_... Anyway, note that there is also [ReactiveObjC](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveObjC).

Comment: Remember, there are constructs in Swift that are not available in Obj-C.  Although, this is drastically better today than it was 7 years ago (tupples, etc.), it's still true.  Not that this helps your immediate problem, but start migrating to Combine to prevent similar problems moving forward.

Comment: @BonanzaDriver yeah, I will take a look to `Combine`, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of RxSwift is the `Event` enum with associated values. This enum cannot be ported into Objective-C.

The answer to your question is... You can't use RxSwift in Objective-C code.

An alternative would be use ReactiveObjC in your Objective-C code and map from RxSwift Observables to ReactiveObjC Signals.